# Is it safe to call realloc() on the pointer you pass into function itself?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

*Note: I am not 100% confident with memory allocation and how it works, but I understand it for the most part.*

When I see `realloc()` being used, I often see people using a new pointer to store the address space instead of using the same/old one. I am wondering if that is necessary.

Am I able to do the following?

```
char *string;
string = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));

...

string = realloc(string, 10 * sizeof(char));
```

More importantly, is this a safe thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) To answer the question of your title: no it is not, because `realloc` can give you a different pointer.

(2) To answer the question of your code: Neither. If `realloc` returns 0,  meaning it can not honor your request to increase the size, you have lost your value of `string` but your old `string` has not been deallocated (memory leak).

Ad. 1: if you could realloc inside a function then you must either pass a double pointer or return the object.

Ad. 2: an example is:

```
char *string, *tmp;
string = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));

...

if ((tmp = realloc(string, 10 * sizeof(char))) == 0) {
    printf("Could not allocate more memory\n);
    return;
}
else
    string= tmp;
```

Comment: How would I be able to reallocate more memory space to an array inside of a loop then? I have an array of strings (collected via the input from uses) that stores each word inside an index in the array. How can I increase the array size to accommodate more words if it's inside a loop?

Comment: Does the example help you?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Thanks for the help, Paul :)